# Vertical space automatically added to fit content to the page

Tags: vertical-spacing, fit

I'm having a problem where Latex is trying to fit the content of a page, by adding unwanted vertical spaces, to somewhat satisfy fitting of the content to the page. An example is shown, where content is situated excessively far from the section's title.

[image]

I figured this out because the next section title is positioned right at the start of the next page, while the content under this section's title ends in such a way that the title and the end of content fit perfectly into the page.

Similar problems with vertical spaces occur for the same reason with `itemize` environment.

Comment: Does putting `\raggedbottom` after `\being{document}` help? If not, pose a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of your code that demonstrates the problem, so we don't have to guess at things like your document class and other settings.

Comment: latex only does this when the document specifies it. Presumably you have `\flushbottom` and some large non-float on the following page preventing a good page break.

Comment: @frabjous Yeah, it helped. The thing is that I'm using some pre-structured templated, which I'm not familiar with.